# print many2many fields on qweb-report

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-10, qweb

I would like to know how I can print in a report qweb a whole field many2many, similar to what happens in the quotes, invoices of the sales module.

Or if it is possible to print them separately in the report

[image: sales quotation]

**cie10_app model**

```
from odoo import models, api, fields
class Cie10Db(models.Model):
  _name = 'cie10.list'
  _rec_name = 'detalleCie'
  codCie = fields.Char('Codigo Cie10')
  detalleCie = fields.Char('Detalle Diagnostico')
```

**cie10_informed**

```
from odoo import models, fields
class DiagRec(models.Model):
     _name = 'info.cie10'
     ob_cie10 = fields.Many2one('cie10.list',string='Dx (CIE 10)')
     ob_codCie10 = fields.Char(related='ob_cie10.codCie')
     ob_observaciones = fields.Char('Observaciones')
```

**informed_app**

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
class InfMed(models.Model):
    dx1 = fields.Many2many('info.cie10')
```

I need to print the whole field many2many in the report qweb

**informed_report**

```
<span t-field="o.tratRec1"/>
```

[image]

but I only get this

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use *for loop* to print many2many field value.

Try with following code:

```
<tr t-foreach="o.many2many_field" t-as="l">
   <td>
       <span t-field="l.name"/>
   </td>
</tr>
```